# Why docker compose up --build doesnt find a file that is on the working directory even with full path?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a [medusajs](https://medusajs.com) Docker image.

I followed all the steps in the [quick start guide](https://docs.medusajs.com/quickstart/quick-start-docker/), but when doing `sudo docker compose up --build` in the root folder of the project, I receive the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "~/medusaPR/micruniverse-store-engine/develop.sh": stat ~/medusaPR/micruniverse-store-engine/develop.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Edit: This is the output after making those corrections to the publication of the Dockerfiles and the docker-compose, now for the new errors, can you point me in the right direction pls? From what I can see, all the steps of the build are complete, but then at the end when executing seems to be missing files or permission.

Sorry for the inconvenience, thanks for your great assistance :D

```
random0perator@random0perator:~/medusaPR/micruniverse-store-engine$ sudo docker compose up --build
[+] Building 5.1s (39/39) FINISHED                                                                                                          
 => [storefront:test internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [backend:test internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [admin:test internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [storefront:test internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                      0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [admin:test internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [backend:test internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [admin:test internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                              0.8s
 => [backend:test internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:17.1.0                                                            0.0s
 => [backend:test internal] load build context                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 4.62kB                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [backend:test 1/9] FROM docker.io/library/node:17.1.0                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 2/9] WORKDIR /app/medusa                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 3/9] COPY package.json .                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 4/9] RUN apt-get update                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 5/9] RUN apt-get install -y python                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 6/9] RUN npm install -g npm@latest                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 7/9] RUN npm install -g @medusajs/medusa-cli@latest                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 8/9] RUN npm install --loglevel=error                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [backend:test 9/9] COPY . .                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [admin:test] exporting to image                                                                                                    0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:19d5d8cb37b3e0a9fd95f01c0afaa2862872a3cc68522504afd349bca4f18290                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/backend:test                                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:2b8d52804d62799a489c22e732cc79dd805ea0e82e1b66f1ed022c77e9e85164                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/storefront:test                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:0ae7ad72057373eb371b515ebd55b4536ef97b0e4d809abf99c57ef9f8499dc4                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/admin:test                                                                                          0.0s
 => [storefront:test  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/node:latest@sha256:ebd1096a66c724af78abb11e6c81eb05b85fcbe8920af2c24d42b6df6aab268  0.0s
 => [admin:test internal] load build context                                                                                           4.0s
 => => transferring context: 8.40MB                                                                                                    3.5s
 => [storefront:test internal] load build context                                                                                      2.9s
 => => transferring context: 5.91MB                                                                                                    2.8s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 2/9] WORKDIR /app/storefront                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 3/9] COPY . .                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 4/9] RUN rm -rf node_modules                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 5/9] RUN apt-get update                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 6/9] RUN npm install -g npm@latest                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 7/9] RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 8/9] RUN npm install sharp                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [storefront:test 9/9] RUN npm install --loglevel=error                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  2/10] WORKDIR /app/admin                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  3/10] COPY . .                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  4/10] RUN rm -rf node_modules                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  5/10] RUN apt-get update                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  6/10] RUN npm install -g npm@latest                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  7/10] RUN npm install sharp                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  8/10] RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test  9/10] RUN npm install --loglevel=error                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [admin:test 10/10] RUN npm run build &> /dev/null                                                                           0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 5/0
 ⠿ Container medusapr-postgres-1  Created                                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container cache                Created                                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusa-server        Created                                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusa-storefront    Created                                                                                              0.0s
 ⠿ Container medusa-admin         Created                                                                                              0.0s
Attaching to cache, medusa-admin, medusa-server, medusa-storefront, medusapr-postgres-1
cache                | 1:C 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.835 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
cache                | 1:C 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.837 # Redis version=7.0.4, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
cache                | 1:C 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.838 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.844 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.848 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.849 # Server initialized
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.850 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.853 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.0.4
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.853 * RDB age 24 seconds
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.853 * RDB memory usage when created 0.82 Mb
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.854 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.854 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
cache                | 1:M 30 Jul 2022 20:37:21.854 * Ready to accept connections
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-30 20:37:21.962 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-30 20:37:21.962 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-30 20:37:22.105 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-30 20:37:22.446 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-07-30 20:36:57 UTC
medusapr-postgres-1  | 2022-07-30 20:37:22.505 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
medusa-server        | medusa develop
medusa-server        | 
medusa-server        | Start development server. Watches file and rebuilds when something changes
medusa-server        | 
medusa-server        | Options:
medusa-server        |   --verbose                Turn on verbose output  [boolean] [default: false]
medusa-server        |   --no-color, --no-colors  Turn off the color in output  [boolean] [default: false]
medusa-server        |   --json                   Turn on the JSON logger  [boolean] [default: false]
medusa-server        |   -H, --host               Set host. Defaults to localhost  [string] [default: "localhost"]
medusa-server        |   -p, --port               Set port. Defaults to 9000 (set by env.PORT) (otherwise defaults 9000)  [string] [default: "9000"]
medusa-server        |   -h, --help               Show help  [boolean]
medusa-server        |   -v, --version            Show the version of the Medusa CLI and the Medusa package in the current project  [boolean]
medusa-server        | babel:
medusa-server        |   src does not exist
medusa-server        | Error: Command failed: "/app/medusa/node_modules/.bin/babel" src -d dist
medusa-server        |     at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
medusa-server        |     at execSync (node:child_process:900:15)
medusa-server        |     at /app/medusa/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:82:42
medusa-server        |     at step (/app/medusa/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:33:23)
medusa-server        |     at Object.next (/app/medusa/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:14:53)
medusa-server        |     at /app/medusa/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:8:71
medusa-server        |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
medusa-server        |     at __awaiter (/app/medusa/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:4:12)
medusa-server        |     at default_1 (/app/medusa/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa/dist/commands/develop.js:74:12)
medusa-server        |     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@medusajs/medusa-cli/dist/create-cli.js:260:7 {
medusa-server        |   status: 2,
medusa-server        |   signal: null,
medusa-server        |   output: [ null, null, null ],
medusa-server        |   pid: 13,
medusa-server        |   stdout: null,
medusa-server        |   stderr: null
medusa-server        | }
medusa-server exited with code 0
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    |  ERROR
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | gatsby develop
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | Start development server. Watches files, rebuilds, and hot reloads if something
medusa-storefront    | changes
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | Options:
medusa-storefront    |   --verbose                   Turn on verbose output  [boolean] [default: false]
medusa-storefront    |   --no-color, --no-colors     Turn off the color in output  [boolean] [default:
medusa-storefront    | false]
medusa-storefront    |   --json                      Turn on the JSON logger  [boolean] [default:
medusa-storefront    | false]
medusa-storefront    |   -H, --host                  Set host. Defaults to localhost  [string]
medusa-storefront    | [default: "localhost"]
medusa-storefront    |   -p, --port                  Set port. Defaults to 8000  [string] [default:
medusa-storefront    | "8000"]
medusa-storefront    |   -o, --open                  Open the site in your (default) browser for you.
medusa-storefront    | [boolean]
medusa-storefront    |   -S, --https                 Use HTTPS. See
medusa-storefront    | https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/local-https/ as a guide  [boolean]
medusa-storefront    |   -c, --cert-file             Custom HTTPS cert file (also required: --https,
medusa-storefront    | --key-file). See https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/local-https/  [string] [default:
medusa-storefront    | ""]
medusa-storefront    |   -k, --key-file              Custom HTTPS key file (also required: --https,
medusa-storefront    | --cert-file). See https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/local-https/  [string] [default:
medusa-storefront    |  ""]
medusa-storefront    |   --ca-file                   Custom HTTPS CA certificate file (also required:
medusa-storefront    | --https, --cert-file, --key-file).  See
medusa-storefront    | https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/local-https/  [string] [default: ""]
medusa-storefront    |   --graphql-tracing           Trace every graphql resolver, may have performance
medusa-storefront    |  implications  [boolean] [default: false]
medusa-storefront    |   --open-tracing-config-file  Tracer configuration file (OpenTracing
medusa-storefront    | compatible). See https://gatsby.dev/tracing  [string]
medusa-storefront    |   --inspect                   Opens a port for debugging. See
medusa-storefront    | https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-the-build-process/  [number]
medusa-storefront    |   --inspect-brk               Opens a port for debugging. Will block until
medusa-storefront    | debugger is attached. See
medusa-storefront    | https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-the-build-process/  [number]
medusa-storefront    |   -h, --help                  Show help  [boolean]
medusa-storefront    |   -v, --version               Show the version of the Gatsby CLI and the Gatsby
medusa-storefront    | package in the current project  [boolean]
medusa-storefront    | 

medusa-storefront    |  ERROR
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | gatsby <develop> can only be run for a gatsby site.
medusa-storefront    | Either the current working directory does not contain a valid package.json or
medusa-storefront    | 'gatsby' is not specified as a dependency
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront    | 
medusa-storefront exited with code 1
medusa-admin         | 
medusa-admin         |  ERROR
medusa-admin         | 
medusa-admin         | Initiated Worker with invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable:
medusa-admin         | --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
medusa-admin         | 

medusa-admin         | 
medusa-admin         |   Error: Initiated Worker with invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable: --openssl-lega
medusa-admin         |   cy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - errors:387 new NodeError
medusa-admin         |     node:internal/errors:387:5
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - worker:195 new Worker
medusa-admin         |     node:internal/worker:195:13
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - ThreadsWorker.js:51 ThreadsWorker.start
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/workers/lib/threads/ThreadsWorker.js:51:19
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - Worker.js:104 Worker.fork
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/workers/lib/Worker.js:104:23
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - WorkerFarm.js:232 WorkerFarm.startChild
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/workers/lib/WorkerFarm.js:232:12
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - WorkerFarm.js:394 WorkerFarm.startMaxWorkers
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/workers/lib/WorkerFarm.js:394:14
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - WorkerFarm.js:139 new WorkerFarm
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/workers/lib/WorkerFarm.js:139:10
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - Parcel.js:565 createWorkerFarm
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/core/lib/Parcel.js:565:10
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - Parcel.js:232 Parcel._init
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/core/lib/Parcel.js:232:20
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - Parcel.js:273 Parcel.run
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[@parcel]/core/lib/Parcel.js:273:7
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - compile-gatsby-files.ts:67 compileGatsbyFiles
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[gatsby]/src/utils/parcel/compile-gatsby-files.ts:67:29
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         |   - initialize.ts:172 initialize
medusa-admin         |     [admin]/[gatsby]/src/services/initialize.ts:172:3
medusa-admin         |   
medusa-admin         | 
not finished compile gatsby files - 0.308s
medusa-admin         | 
medusa-admin exited with code 1
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your Dockerfile. `develop.sh` seems to be the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) of your container. The build could be failing because it's not being copied properly into the image.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: Sure, sorry about that, As homer simpson, this is my first day :D

Will take that into account.
@CodyEakins
`
 FROM node:17.1.0

WORKDIR ~/medusaPR/micruniverse-store-engine

COPY package.json .

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y python

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

RUN npm install -g @medusajs/medusa-cli@latest

RUN npm install --loglevel=error

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["./develop.sh", "develop"]
~
`code`

Comment: If its worth something, this project is a marketplace, so I'm running docker-compose from the root folder, where is located a folder for the backend, front and admin panel. This dockerfile is from the backend folder.

Comment: If this `dockerfile` is from the backend folder, it should be built within the backend folder, not some "root" directory above it. The build context sent to Docker determines what files are available to COPY when you use relative references, for example: `COPY ./ ./`. If you're trying to build your image from a parent directory, without adjusting your `dockerfile` or build arguments, then that's probably why your build is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:17.1.0

WORKDIR ~/medusaPR/micruniverse-store-engine

COPY package.json ./

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python

RUN npm install -g npm@latest
RUN npm install -g @medusajs/medusa-cli@latest
RUN npm install --loglevel=error

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["./develop.sh", "develop"]
```

... and most of the instructions look alright to me. Your entrypoint is being properly copied in. What is odd, however, is your `ENTRYPOINT` instruction:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./develop.sh", "develop"]
```

Referencing the [documentation on ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), we can see that your Dockerfile is using the exec form:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
```

... which means that your `develop.sh` is your executable and `develop` is a parameter to it. However, if we take a look at `develop.sh`, we can see that it does not take parameters. It already has the "develop" parameter:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#Run migrations to ensure the database is updated
medusa migrations run

#Start development environment
medusa develop
```

So maybe change your ENTRYPOINT to: `ENTRYPOINT ["./develop.sh"]` to fix the problem?

---

Also a second possible cause, based on my own earlier comment:

> If this dockerfile is from the backend folder, it **MUST** be built within the backend folder, not some "root" directory above it.
>
> The build context sent to Docker determines what files are available
> to COPY when you use relative references, for example: COPY ./ ./. If
> you're trying to build your image from a parent directory, without
> adjusting your dockerfile or build arguments, then that's probably why
> your build is failing.

Your Dockerfile can't copy `develop.sh` into the image because its not in the parent directory; it's in the `backend` child directory.

Comment: I'm so glad to receive your help, before your explanation I really didn't understand what were going on while docker run those commands, now I can see. As you said, when using docker-compose, each Dockerfile for each service must be on its own folder and only the docker-compose.yml should be in the root folder of all the project.

About the develop.sh file, seems to be running a command to "seed" the database, nothing more than that, I were able to see that is the equivalent of running in console medusa migrations run, that update the tables of the database I think.

Comment: @CristianSteveDavidMachado -- That's partially correct; you can use a parent/root level `docker-compose.yml` to deploy your entire stack (frontend, backend, etc). However, you must still specify the [context option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context) for each service in your stack if you want to build each service's image locally. Otherwise, docker will assume the context is `/parent-folder` instead of `/parent-folder/backend` when trying to build your backend image.

Comment: Also, your entrypoint should not only seed the database if you intend to have a long running server; [medusa's default develop.sh](https://github.com/medusajs/medusa-starter-default/blob/master/develop.sh) both seeds the databse and runs the server in development mode. Did you edit your version of `develop.sh`? Think of the entrypoint as the default command that Docker runs when starting your container. It bootstraps your app. It's the starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight on this matter. After running everything again, it seems to be able to finish the build, all tasks seem to be ok, but now I understand from my log of the build that is having issues finding the package file in the front service, 

So, my question is, if I need help with a different issue a should set this one as resolved and create a new one right?

Comment: I'd file a separate issue, even if it's tedious. It helps keep things organized.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command will format the .sh  file correctly.

dos2unix.exe your-file.sh

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the entrypoint, the custom script develop.sh need to have +x, and it need to be available in path, so what u can change is
after `COPY . .`  you add

```
COPY --chmod=777 develop.sh /usr/local/bin/develop.sh
```

that will place the the sh file under `/usr/local/bin` so it's always available in $PATH, and the chmod 777 to make sure that all permission added (including x)